# Check for present User ID in Blazor PWA Application,I want to check if this User is in the List with the users data I hard coded

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, local-storage, userid

This is the logic I am trying to write,I want to get the users from my hard coded list with users and get the id from the localStorage of the user that tries to currently login with it(the Id is like the password in this case,they have separate real Id,called userId),but what I want to do is take the Id that they typed from the local storage and check if this Id is already registered.I hope that was clear.

```
private DataModel data = new DataModel();



public class DataModel
 {

     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string UserId { get; set; }

     public string SMSCode { get; set; }

     public string Token { get; set; }

    
 }


 private List<DataModel> users = new List<DataModel>();



 private async void HandleLogin()
 {

     Console.WriteLine("Log me in!");
     var id = 0;

     var userslist = await IuserService.getUsers();
     var usersfirstid = userslist.First();
     
   

     if (usersfirstid.Id == 0)
     {
         id = id + 1;
     }
     else
     {
         id = id + 1;
     }


     var user = userslist.Where(x => x.Id != id).First();

    

     if (user==null)
     {
         errorMessage = true;
     }
     else
     {
         var randomId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
         id = id + 1;
         await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<int>("id", id);
         await LocalStorage.SetItemAsync<string>("userId", randomId);
     }

     await AuthStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();


     NavManager.NavigateTo("/verificar");


 }
```

Comment: You should give some information and what is going wrong and clean a bit your code. A few things are irrelevant/useless(`data` never used, an if statement that does the same thing in both cases etc...).

Comment: Hello,data is used just in this statement it's not,So I want to check some of the hard coded users has the id of the user that tried to login now,etc check if this Id is already registered.The users data is in simpe (...List<DataModel> users = ....).

Comment: I don t get the point of your piece of code: you start with id = 0, then you get the first user (in list order, not necessarily id order), then you do nothing with it and sets id to 1. After that you get again the first user not having the id == 1. Then you save in the local storage the id having the value 2, it (almost) does not matter the content of the list of users.

Comment: By the way, `user` cannot be null. `First` throws an exception if the list is empty.

Comment: That was just for testing if it sees and goes inside the if statements,because I implemented other things later,however I am trying to connect an HTTP adress and take the data from the input field and pass it to the DataModel object,(user = new DataModel{Id = currentId(the id from the input)}